# Google Maps V3 panTo offset

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am having the same issue as this folk ( [link](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api/browse_thread/thread/cbd6fab9c0fb5203) ), trying to offset panTo coordinates. The only solution I've found so far is to use panBy after I've used panTo.

```
map.panTo( position );
map.panBy(120, -70);
```

Those familiar with the Google Maps API will know that the issue with this approach is that it will trigger a smooth animation after panTo, to move to panBy. I wonder if there is a better approach?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API V3: Offset panTo() by x pixels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146676/google-maps-api-v3-offset-panto-by-x-pixels)