# Google Maps API V3: Offset panTo() by x pixels

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a some UI elements on the right of my map (sometimes), and I'd like to offset my panTo() calls (sometimes).

So I figured:

1. get the original latlng
2. convert it to screen pixels
3. add an offset
4. convert it back to latlng.

But I must misunderstand what Google Maps API refers to as the "Point Plane":
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Projection

Here is my code that seems to offset by lat-long:

```js
            function getCentreOffset( alatlng ) {
                    var PIXEL_OFFSET= 100; 
                    var aPoint = me.gmap.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(alatlng);
                    aPoint.x=aPoint.x + OFFSET;
                    return me.gmap.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(aPoint);
            }
```

Comment: is this question answered already? If yes, then all below "Answer edit" should be posted as an answer, and then accepted!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Here's a simpler version of Ashley's solution:

```
google.maps.Map.prototype.panToWithOffset = function(latlng, offsetX, offsetY) {
    var map = this;
    var ov = new google.maps.OverlayView();
    ov.onAdd = function() {
        var proj = this.getProjection();
        var aPoint = proj.fromLatLngToContainerPixel(latlng);
        aPoint.x = aPoint.x+offsetX;
        aPoint.y = aPoint.y+offsetY;
        map.panTo(proj.fromContainerPixelToLatLng(aPoint));
    }; 
    ov.draw = function() {}; 
    ov.setMap(this); 
};
```

You can then use it like this:

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: latlng
});

setTimeout(function() { map.panToWithOffset(latlng, 0, 150); }, 1000);
```

Here is a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/3rtJX/).

Let me explain in detail. This extends the Map object itself. So you can use it just like `panTo()` with extra parameters for offsets. This uses the `fromLatLngToContainerPixel()` and `fromContainerPixelToLatLng()` methods of the [MapCanvasProjecton](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapCanvasProjection) class. This object has no contructor and has to be gotten from the `getProjection()` method of the [OverlayView](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#OverlayView) class; the OverlayView class is used for the creation of custom overlays by implementing its interface, but here we just use it directly. Because `getProjection()` is only available after `onAdd()` has been called. The `draw()` method is called after `onAdd()` and is defined for our instance of OverlayView to be a function that does nothing. Not doing so will otherwise cause an error.

Comment: Thanks a million 'Dean Or', this is perfect, up until now i was mucking about with setCenter (to center on lat/lng) followed by a panBy call (to pan by pixels) but your code is alot nicer in every possible way. Thanks again!! (btw this should really be in the google maps wiki somewhere, maybe suggest it?)

Comment: Thank you for this, I am using this custom `panToWithOffset` function but I'd like to also set the zoom... if I do that before calling this function; it messes up the location. What should I do?

Comment: Looks like this has Problems with the new renderer:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/new-renderer

Answer (score 7):

Answer by Dean looks a lot cleaner as said in some comments, but was looking a little complicated to me. This single line solution is looking more elegant to me.

```
var map = $('#map_canvas').gmap3("get")
map.panBy(-500,-500); // (x,y)
```

Set center of map first. Then panyBy will shift the center in (x,y) direction. The more negative x, map will shift right. The more negative y, map will shift down.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the answer here: [How to call fromLatLngToDivPixel in Google Maps API V3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538681/how-to-call-fromlatlngtodivpixel-in-google-maps-api-v3/7018754#7018754)

First create function/prototpe to access the map's projection (difficult in V3)

```js
//declare function/prototpe
function CanvasProjectionOverlay() {}
//define..
CanvasProjectionOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
CanvasProjectionOverlay.prototype.constructor = CanvasProjectionOverlay;
CanvasProjectionOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function(){};
CanvasProjectionOverlay.prototype.draw = function(){};
CanvasProjectionOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function(){};

var gmap;
var canvasProjectionOverlay;
var PIXEL_OFFSET= 100;

function showUluru(isOffset=false){
    //create map
    var gmap = new google.maps.Map($('#map_canvas', {});
    //create projection
    canvasProjectionOverlay = new CanvasProjectionOverlay();
    canvasProjectionOverlay.setMap(gmap);
    var uluruRock = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.335448,135.745076);

    if (isOffset)
            uluruRock  = getCentreOffset(uluruRock);

    gmap.panTo( uluruRock )
}


//Use this function on LatLng you want to PanTo();
function getCentreOffset( alatlng ) {
    var proj = canvasProjectionOverlay.getProjection();
    var aPoint = proj.fromLatLngToContainerPixel(alatlng);
    aPoint.x=aPoint.x+PIXEL_OFFSET;
    return proj.fromContainerPixelToLatLng(aPoint);
}
```