# Google Maps API v.3 - How to panTo Top_Left (X,Y) from marker on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here is my code

```
function init_map() {

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(31.75664276376096, 35.56389920898436),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'), myOptions);

    var locations = [
        ['Name1', 0, 0],
        ['Name2', 1, 1]
    ];

    var infoWindowContent = ['some content here']

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
        marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);

        bounds.extend(position);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            icon: './images/content/mapPin.png',
            title: locations[i][0]
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {

                map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
                infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);

                var iwOuter = jQuery('.gm-style-iw');

                var iwBackground = iwOuter.prev();

                iwBackground.children(':nth-child(2)').css({
                    'display': 'none'
                });

                iwBackground.children(':nth-child(4)').css({
                    'display': 'none'
                });

                var ceva = jQuery(window).width();

                if(ceva <= 400){
                    iwOuter.parent().parent().css({
                        'left': '0',
                        'top': '0'
                    });
                    iwOuter.children(':nth-child(1)').addClass('gm-style-child').css({
                        'width': '100%'
                    });
                } else if (ceva <= 768) {
                    iwOuter.parent().parent().css({
                        'left': '15px',
                        'top': '0'
                    });
                    map.panTo(marker.getPosition());

               } else {
                    iwOuter.parent().parent().css({
                        'left': '220px',
                        'top': '180px'
                    });
               }

               iwOuter.parent().css({
                   'width': '260px'
               });

               iwOuter.children().css({
                   'max-height': 'none',
                   'overflow': 'visible'
               });

               iwOuter.children().children().css({
                   'overflow': 'visible'
               });

               iwBackground.children(':nth-child(1)').css({
                   'display': 'none'
               });

               iwBackground.children(':nth-child(3)').find('div').children().css({
                   'display': 'none'
               });

               var iwCloseBtn = iwOuter.next();

               iwCloseBtn.addClass('close-icon').css({
                       'display': 'none'
               });
            }
        })(marker, i));

        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }

    var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
        this.setZoom(8);
        google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
```

I have the infoWindow popup from right of the marker. Whenever i click on the mapPin it centers the map on the pin.

> map.panTo(marker.getPosition());

So what i want is that when i click on a marker to move the map slightly bit to the left and top. So the marker would appear in the top and maybe -100 x offset so when i click the marker - the popup would be visible and you would not have to drag the map to see all the info in the popup.

I will add some images to have a better understanding.

Right now it looks something like this.

[image]

And i want something like this only for desktop version as for the mobile it works perfect.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea how to achieve this. Thank you!

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146676/google-maps-api-v3-offset-panto-by-x-pixels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. All i had to do was to add the disableAutoPan to the infoWindow

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    disableAutoPan: true
}),
```